# throws IllegalArgumentException throwing in IDE but not printing out

Tags: java

IllegalArgumentException is throwing in IDE but not printing out
how can I add a print line statement to get the exception to print out to screen when it is thrown?

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Test scores must have a value less than 100 and greater than 0.");
```

Edit: code below to working code now from all the comments, fixing it, yet one last issue, is when I get the error to trip, not having the output still displayed after the error shows on the screen

```
package driver;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat; 


public class Driver
{
    private double[] scoreArray;

    public Driver(double[] test) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        scoreArray = new double[test.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++)
        {
            if (test[i] < 0 || test[i] > 100)
                System.err.println("Test scores must have a value less than 100 and greater than 0.");
               // throw new IllegalArgumentException("Test scores must have a value less than 100 and greater than 0.");
            else
                scoreArray[i] = test[i];
        }
    }

    public double getAverage()
    {
        double total = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++)
            total += scoreArray[i];

        return (total / scoreArray.length);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {  
        int score = 0;
       // int scores = 0;

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter number of test scores:");
        score = userInput.nextInt();

        double[] scoreArray = new double[score];

        for (int i = 0; i <= score - 1; i++)
        {    
            System.out.print("Enter test score " + (i + 1)+ ":");
            //scoreArray[scores] = userInput.nextDouble();  
            scoreArray[i] = userInput.nextDouble();
        }
        DecimalFormat ft = new DecimalFormat("####");
        ft = new DecimalFormat("0.0"); 
        Driver testScore  = new Driver(scoreArray);
        //System.out.println(driver.getAverage);
        System.out.println(ft.format(testScore.getAverage()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Catch it and print its `getMessage()`?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to throw this exception unconditionally in the `main` method?

Comment: If you don't catch an exception, it will get printed. Are you sure it's not being printed? What IDE are you using?

Comment: using netbeans IDE and the online IDE for my classroom 
and both are saying it is not throwing as a print out, but instead throwing inside the IDE
trying to find a way to both throw in the IDE and when thrown also print out to screen

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor may throw this exception, so you should use it like this

```
TestScores testScore;
try {
    testScore  = new TestScores(scoreArray);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Tried to put this in and maybe i put in the wrong spot because it didn't work.
Thought i did find if i replace

`throw new IllegalArgumentException("Test scores must have a value less than 100 and greater than 0."); `

---- with -----

`System.out.println("Test scores must have a value less than 100 and greater than 0.");`

But not sure if this will solve my problem because it prints out now, but not sure if it counts as a throw, wish i could find a way to do both, throw the exception annnnd print out

Answer (score 1):

IllegalArgumentException extends RuntimeException so in normal cases your Compiler/IDE won't force you to catch it or throw it back to caller. If you do decide to catch it though then you may print it out in your logger as such:

```
log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
```

Comment: In the catch(...) block you can use your logger to print the error message to the log file and the in the very next statement you may throw it back to the caller which would server your purpose. Also, if you decide to use System println instead of logger then its better to use System.err.println instead of System.out.println since this is an error. And then the next statement may be followed up throwing it back to the caller.